# Web3js send ERC20 token with my own mining machine

Tags: web3js, mining, erc-20

Is it possible to send custom ERC20 token using my own mining machine?

We have a big website where we are going to use our own Custom token but the problem is when we send tokens to the user we need to pay some gas fee and we want to avoid this fee so idea is to use our own mining machine.

Please suggest us best advice if you can.

If it is possible then how?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an erc20 token in ethereum's mainnet, you need to pay your transaction costs in form of gas to the miners, there is no way to get around that, if you want to become a miner, you will either mine a pool and not choose which transactions go into your block, or mine solo, meaning that you either have an unreasonable high initial investment, or you wouldn't be mining too often.

If you want to use ethereum's features, without paying transaction costs, you will need to create your own ethereum instance, or use one of the scalability solution alternatives, I'd look into [plasma cash](https://medium.com/novamining/plasma-cash-new-scalability-solution-for-the-ethereum-network-f7c0b889db7d), or the [loom network](https://medium.com/loom-network/loom-network-plasma-5e86caaadef2), and if you don't need everyone in the world to access your blockchain, you can always choose to create your own [permissioned/private chain](https://wiki.parity.io/Chain-specification)

Comment: Thank you, here are some questions. 
If I create my own blockchain is it possible to merge later with main Ethereum blockchain?
Is my private blockchain tokens will be traded into trade exchange?

Comment: Rather than merging with ethereum (You technically can by deploying the latest state in your chain to ethereum), I'd look into bridges, for example, with parity bridges you could move tokens from ethereum where your pay gas to your private network which is more centralized but can have 0 gas costs